# Почему выводится цифра 9? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Почему выводится 9 если при i = 9 j = 3, 9 % 3 == 0 т.е условие true и должен сработать continue пропустив alert

```js
Next:for (i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
  for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) continue Next;
    alert(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: ну а что, кроме 3 и 9 чисел не встречается в цикле?  Открой отладку и построчно посмотри что где происходит на строках кода, особенно в интересующих моментах (особенно последняя итерация)

Comment: `i = 9`, `j = 2` -> `alert(i)`